# Synonym / duplicate tag? [amazon-api-gateway] vs [aws-api-gateway]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I found that the [amazon-api-gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-api-gateway) and [aws-api-gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-api-gateway) may refer to the same thing.  I'm not sure though as it's not in my area of expertise.  [amazon-api-gateway] has only 219 questions at this time, whereas the other tag has 7,187 questions.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me, a quick scan suggests something like 37% of posts tagged with `[amazon-api-gateway]` are also already tagged with `[aws-api-gateway]`.  And I'd just generally like to see AWS things tagged with `aws-*` to avoid confusion with Amazon things.